How to Obtain inboundPlanId and shipmentId for Shipments Created via Third-Party Applications in SP API v2024-03-20
Currently, I'm retrieving information only through version v0. I make a request, receive the shipmentId, and based on that shipmentId, I get information about which SKUs I've sent and how many Amazon has received.
Now, when I try using the new version, almost all requests require an inboundPlanId and shipmentId, but I have no idea how to obtain this information. Logically, they are provided when I create shipments through the API. But what do I do in cases where shipments are created through third-party apps like 2D......., and I end up with nothing, so I can't make requests using the new version?
When I download all shipments—ACTIVE, VOIDED, or SHIPPED—they have no names, so I don't even understand which ones they are because the request returns an empty field for the name. Can someone help me with advice on how web applications like Seller...... handle this? I would be very grateful for any help.
At this moment I'm using v0 , but not able to get information like createdate or lastuptated date of shipment , also I'm not able to get tracking numbers of shipments because all this requests requires inboundplanid and shipmentid
import requests

# Endpoint URLs
shipment_url = "https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/fba/inbound/v0/shipments"

# Function to get shipments
def get_shipments(access_token):
    headers = {
        'x-amz-access-token': access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    params = {
        'ShipmentStatusList': 'SHIPPED,WORKING,CANCELLED'
    }
    
    response = requests.get(shipment_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print("Error:", response.status_code)
        return None

# Example usage
access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
shipments = get_shipments(access_token)
print(shipments)


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python?Rust?C#?Java? forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.
